# Python pygame modules problems

Tags: python, pygame

I got some problem to understand python `pygame` syntax

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        check_keydown_event(event, ship, ai_settings, bullets, screen)
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        check_keyup_event(event, ship, ai_settings)
```

what I got is that `pygame` is a package name, so we can use `pygame.sprite` to import a class from `sprite` file(module). Now that `pygame` is a package name, where is keyboard constants defined like :

```
pygame.QUIT
pygame.KEYDOWN
```

Comment: they are defined in `pygame.constants` and import inside the file `__init__.py` of the pygame package (`print(dir(pygame.constants))`=

Comment: @PRMoureu yeah, I found a constants which is a .so file in pygame package and it is imported in to __init__.py. So when I use pygame.KEYDOWN, it directly calls the __init__.py. Is that right?

Comment: the file `__init__.py` is called when you execute `import pygame` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

The constants are defined in [`pygame.locals`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/locals.html). If you want to use `QUIT` instead of `pygame.QUIT` and `KEYDOWN` instead of `pygame.KEYDOWN`, you have to import:

```py
from pygame.locals import *
```